# Why my does my Zombie-Pigman-conversion addon result in piglins that take gold in barters but give nothing back?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I coded an addon that allows curing Zombie Pigmen. I thought they would revert to zombies in the Overworld, but they survived as a piglins. But when I try to barter, they just takes the gold and drops nothing.

Here's the code:

```
{
    "format_version": "1.16.0",
    "minecraft:entity": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "minecraft:zombie_pigman",
            "is_spawnable": true,
            "is_summonable": true,
            "is_experimental": false
        },
        "component_groups": {
            "minecraft:pig_zombie_baby": {
                "minecraft:experience_reward": {
                    "on_death": "query.last_hit_by_player ? 12 + (query.equipment_count * Math.Random(1,3)) : 0"
                },
                "minecraft:is_baby": {},
                "minecraft:scale": {
                    "value": 0.5
                }
            },
            "minecraft:pig_zombie_adult": {
                "minecraft:rideable": {
                    "seat_count": 1,
                    "family_types": [
                        "zombie"
                    ],
                    "seats": {
                        "position": [
                            0,
                            1.1,
                            -0.35
                        ],
                        "lock_rider_rotation": 0
                    }
                },
                "minecraft:experience_reward": {
                    "on_death": "query.last_hit_by_player ? 5 + (query.equipment_count * Math.Random(1,3)) : 0"
                }
            },
            "minecraft:pig_zombie_angry": {
                "minecraft:angry": {
                    "duration": 25,
                    "broadcast_anger": true,
                    "broadcast_range": 20,
                    "calm_event": {
                        "event": "minecraft:on_calm",
                        "target": "self"
                    }
                }
            },
            "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm": {
                "minecraft:on_target_acquired": {
                    "event": "minecraft:become_angry",
                    "target": "self"
                }
            },
            "minecraft:strider_jockey": {
                "minecraft:equipment": {
                    "table": "loot_tables/entities/zombified_piglin_rider_gear.json"
                }
            },
            "to_piglin": {
                "minecraft:transformation": {
                    "into": "minecraft:piglin",
                    "begin_transform_sound": "remedy",
                    "transformation_sound": "unfect",
                    "keep_level": true,
                    "delay": {
                        "value": 100,
                        "block_assist_chance": 0.01,
                        "block_radius": 4,
                        "block_chance": 0.3,
                        "block_types": [
                            "minecraft:iron_bars"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "minecraft:spell_effects": {
                    "add_effects": [
                        {
                            "effect": "strength",
                            "duration": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "effect": "heal",
                            "duration": 100
                        }
                    ],
                    "remove_effects": "weakness"
                },
                "minecraft:is_shaking": {}
            }
        },
        "components": {
            "minecraft:breathable": {
                "total_supply": 15,
                "suffocate_time": 0,
                "breathes_water": true
            },
            "minecraft:equip_item": {},
            "minecraft:collision_box": {
                "width": 0.6,
                "height": 1.9
            },
            "minecraft:nameable": {},
            "minecraft:navigation.walk": {
                "is_amphibious": true,
                "can_pass_doors": true,
                "can_open_doors": true,
                "avoid_water": true,
                "avoid_portals": true
            },
            "minecraft:movement.basic": {},
            "minecraft:jump.static": {},
            "minecraft:can_climb": {},
            "minecraft:fire_immune": {},
            "minecraft:type_family": {
                "family": [
                    "zombie_pigman",
                    "undead",
                    "monster",
                    "mob"
                ]
            },
            "minecraft:loot": {
                "table": "loot_tables/entities/zombie_pigman.json"
            },
            "minecraft:equipment": {
                "table": "loot_tables/entities/zombie_pigman_gear.json"
            },
            "minecraft:health": {
                "value": 20,
                "max": 20
            },
            "minecraft:movement": {
                "value": 0.23
            },
            "minecraft:attack": {
                "damage": 5
            },
            "minecraft:despawn": {
                "despawn_from_distance": {}
            },
            "minecraft:shareables": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:netherite_sword",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:diamond_sword",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:iron_sword",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:stone_sword",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:golden_sword",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:wooden_sword",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:netherite_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:diamond_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:iron_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:chainmail_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:golden_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:leather_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:turtle_helmet",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:skull:0",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 7
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:skull:1",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 7
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:carved_pumpkin",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 7
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:netherite_chestplate",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:diamond_chestplate",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:iron_chestplate",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:chainmail_chestplate",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:golden_chestplate",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:leather_chestplate",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:netherite_leggings",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:diamond_leggings",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:iron_leggings",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:chainmail_leggings",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:golden_leggings",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:leather_leggings",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:netherite_boots",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:diamond_boots",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:iron_boots",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:chainmail_boots",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:golden_boots",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:leather_boots",
                        "want_amount": 1,
                        "surplus_amount": 1,
                        "priority": 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.hurt_by_target": {
                "priority": 1
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.mount_pathing": {
                "priority": 2,
                "speed_multiplier": 1.25,
                "target_dist": 0,
                "track_target": true
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.equip_item": {
                "priority": 3
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.melee_attack": {
                "priority": 4,
                "speed_multiplier": 1.5
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.stomp_turtle_egg": {
                "priority": 5,
                "speed_multiplier": 1,
                "search_range": 10,
                "search_height": 2,
                "goal_radius": 1.14,
                "interval": 20
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.pickup_items": {
                "priority": 6,
                "max_dist": 3,
                "goal_radius": 2,
                "speed_multiplier": 1,
                "pickup_based_on_chance": true,
                "can_pickup_any_item": true
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.random_stroll": {
                "priority": 7,
                "speed_multiplier": 1
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.look_at_player": {
                "priority": 8,
                "look_distance": 6,
                "probability": 0.02
            },
            "minecraft:behavior.random_look_around": {
                "priority": 9
            },
            "minecraft:physics": {},
            "minecraft:pushable": {
                "is_pushable": true,
                "is_pushable_by_piston": true
            },
            "minecraft:conditional_bandwidth_optimization": {},
            "minecraft:interact": {
                "interactions": {
                    "on_interact": {
                        "filters": {
                            "all_of": [
                                {
                                    "test": "has_equipment",
                                    "domain": "hand",
                                    "subject": "other",
                                    "value": "golden_apple"
                                },
                                {
                                    "test": "has_component",
                                    "subject": "self",
                                    "value": "minecraft:effect.weakness"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "event": "piglin_converted",
                        "target": "self"
                    },
                    "use_item": true,
                    "interact_text": "action.interact.cure"
                }
            }
        },
        "events": {
            "minecraft:entity_transformed": {
                "sequence": [
                    {
                        "filters": {
                            "test": "has_component",
                            "subject": "other",
                            "value": "minecraft:is_baby"
                        },
                        "add": {
                            "component_groups": [
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_baby",
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "filters": {
                            "test": "has_component",
                            "subject": "other",
                            "operator": "!=",
                            "value": "minecraft:is_baby"
                        },
                        "add": {
                            "component_groups": [
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_adult",
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "minecraft:entity_spawned": {
                "randomize": [
                    {
                        "weight": 95,
                        "remove": {},
                        "add": {
                            "component_groups": [
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_adult",
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 5,
                        "remove": {},
                        "add": {
                            "component_groups": [
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_baby",
                                "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "minecraft:on_calm": {
                "remove": {
                    "component_groups": [
                        "minecraft:pig_zombie_angry"
                    ]
                },
                "add": {
                    "component_groups": [
                        "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "minecraft:become_angry": {
                "remove": {
                    "component_groups": [
                        "minecraft:pig_zombie_calm"
                    ]
                },
                "add": {
                    "component_groups": [
                        "minecraft:pig_zombie_angry"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "minecraft:spawn_as_strider_jockey": {
                "add": {
                    "component_groups": [
                        "minecraft:strider_jockey"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "piglin_converted": {
                "remove": {},
                "add": {
                    "component_groups": [
                        "to_piglin"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It was ripped from the `zombie_villager_v2.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this `"piglin_converted"` object:

```
"piglin_converted": {
    "remove": {},
    "add": {
        "component_groups": [
            "to_piglin"
        ]
    }
}
```

Replace `"add"` with `"replace"` to create:

```
"piglin_converted": {
    "remove": {},
    "replace": {
        "component_groups": [
            "to_piglin"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site Evan! This answer would be easier to follow if you actually included the corrected code in your answer. If you click the "edit" button you can update your answer. You can then use the "{}" button to add some formatting to make the code easier to read as well.